# openldap remove objectClass

Tags: openldap

I could not find a way after a searching around. I'd like to remove posixAccount, which I added to an existing entry. I configured 'uidNumber', 'gidNumber' too. But I can't remove it. In ldif file, I tried to remove the objectClass, I got violation always. I tried to remove 'uidNumber', but got violation certainly. How could I remove an objectClass.

Yang

Answer (score -1):

Find one solution. In one ldif file, delete the objectClass's attrs and itself one after one, first attrs, then objectClass.